# MySQL get all characters before specific character

Tags: mysql, character

I have a table where I extract some values, one column values can contain "value1|value2|value3", but I only want to get the characters before the | - "value1".

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work.. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

> $sql = "SELECT * LEFT('Like', LOCATE('|', 'Like')-1) FROM $tablename
>   WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";

I want to use this for ALL values, not just one field..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need the following statement to get that portion of [ColName]:

```
LEFT([ColName],INSTR([ColName],"|")-1)
```

If you want to select multiple columns into the same recordset column you can union all with something like the following:

```
 SELECT LEFT(ColName,INSTR(ColName,"|")-1) AS FirstValue From $TableName;
 UNION ALL
 SELECT LEFT(ColName2,INSTR(ColName2,"|")-1) AS FirstValue From $TableName;
```

If you want to use this on multiple columns, script the creation of the sql.

Answer (score 7):

Two things: (1) you don't have a comma between your `*` and the expression you're trying to do with `LEFT` and (2) you're putting `like` in quotes, so the functions are working on the constant value `like` instead of your column named `like`. Try putting `like` in backticks.

```
SELECT *, LEFT(`Like`, LOCATE('|', `Like`)-1)
...
```

You can also use the MySQL [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function for this:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Like`, '|', 1)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, like SUBSTRING_INDEX solution more